# PHP-AJAX Multiple Forms Post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arguments

In a module of my PHP application, there are multiple forms, generated with unique id's and names by server side as "formToProcess1, formToProcess2, ... , fromToProcessN". However, there are two ajax functions that handles the request of each form, which both of them gets form name in string as argument, like following:

```
 function ajaxReject(formToProcess)
    {
     var ajaxRequest;
        //document.getElementById('divUploadResultAjax').style.display = 'none';



        try
        {
          ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e)
        {
          try
          {
             ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
          }
          catch (e) 
          {
             try
             {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
              }
              catch (e)
              {
                alert('Something is wrong with your browser, AJAX not working!');
               return false;
             }
          }
        }

        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
          if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
          {
             var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('divUploadResultAjax');
             ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
             //document.getElementById('loadingAjaxIcon').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById('divUploadResultAjax').style.display = 'block';
          }
        }

        var updName         = document.forms['formToProcess'].getElementById('userName').value;

                      //i'll get other elements values for query string to send if i can get this one first :)




        var queryString = '?name=' + updName + '&lastname=' + updLastname + '&bio=' + updBio + '&country=' + updCountry + '&cams=' + updCams + '&fb=' + updFacebook + '&twitter=' + updTwitter + '&processRequest=' + RequestProcess;

        alert (queryString);
        return;


        ajaxRequest.open('GET', 'dashboardUpdateProfile.php' + queryString, true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null); 
                        }



#Every form in the php page is generated like following:

        echo '

                                        <div id="divUploadResultAjax">
                                            <form name="profileUpdater'. $formCounter .'">
                                                <input type="hidden" id="uluid" name="uluid" value="'.$UL_UploadID.'" />
                                                <table class="tg" style="width: 100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 250px; color: #000000;" colspan="3">
                                                            <h3>Upload ID #'.$UL_UploadID.' </h3> (Uploaded On '.$NewCreateDate.')
                                                        </td>
    ...
    ...
    bla bla bla
    ...
    ...

    ----> this is where i call functions in each form.
    <input type="button" class="btnRegister" name="updateProfile"     onclick="ajaxReject(\'profileUpdater'. $formCounter .'\')" value="Reject" />
             <input type="button" class="btnRegister" name="updateProfile" onclick="ajaxApprove()"     value="Approve" />
```

I'm not really sure what is wrong. When i call the function with button click, it works perfectly until end of if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4),  after that, when i'm trying to get the var updName        = document.forms['formToProcess'].getElementById('userName').value; function crashes. What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use something like `var updName = document.getElementById('userName').value;`.

I don't find username element in the form? Is it there in your actual code?

Comment: yes, there is an element named userName (input) in my form. i can get its value by simple doing the one i mentioned above but when it contains same names multiple times in other forms as well, it only gets the first one only, not in other forms. Thats why i need to make something like: document.forms[formName].getElementById('userName').value; but it doesn't work and i'm stuck here :(

Comment: Why don't you use the element name like `var updName = document.forms[formToProcess].userName.value;`

Comment: Did you notice that i'm not using getElementById and no ' (quotes) around formToProcess?

Comment: ok it works like charm, i had syntax error. Thank you so much!